# AtomLinter - Create new linter for GAMS language

Tags: atom-editor, gams-math, linter

I am interested in working (playing around) on a GAMS linter provider for AtomLinter. However, I could not figure out an entry point for the project, as most existing linter packages seem to link the Atom linter package with existing linters.

Though the features required for a GAMS linter may be comparibly little (indentation, check for spurious commas/missing semicolons as a beginning), I'm fearing that this ends up being way more work than I'am hoping for right now. So if anyone has some advice for me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: All Atom packages that provide code review, interpreting, or compiling are going to reference an external binary that actually understands how to read the code. If there's no existing linter program for GAMS, you'd have to start with that, which is a much larger project.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the explanation! I will start fiddling around on the actual linter then, might take a couple years from now though :)